# What does "Lecture du compteur" mean in this context?

Tags: traduction

Whilst "Lecture du compteur" translates to "meter reading", I'm not sure this is the correct kind of reading. Can anyone provide a more natural translation please?

This is in the context of a gas or electricity meter reading.

Comment: Please don't roll back improvements to your question. “Request for translation” is not a meaningful title at all. Even with the improved title, your question is still not clear. **What's the context**?

Comment: "Improvements" are subjective. Stack Exchange provides me with the option of rolling them back so should do so if I feel it is necessary. In all fairness, "Request for translation" is exactly what I was after and I have had a number of replies providing more than adequate responses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would add the full sentence where you find the text to be sure of the context.

I told it as *Lecture du compteur* can be used for a meter reading if it's for the actual action of the sentence.

Ex;

*Dans la ville où je vis, je dois faire la lecture du compteur d'eau  de ma maison tous les six mois.*

jlliagre's answer is correct too, as the words could be used for la *Valeur affichée (sur le compteur)* too.

Ex; La valeur affichée sur la jauge d'essence est celle de la dernière graduation.

Answer (score 2):

"Reading" has more than one meaning in English but I guess what you look for is:

> *Valeur affichée (sur le compteur)*.